# Express 4 and file session store

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

I'm usint Express 4, and I'm trying to save session values using [session-file-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store), this is the configuration I use in `app.js`:

```
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(expressSession);

app.use(
    expressSession({
        name: 'connect.sid',
        store: new FileStore(),
        cookie : { maxAge : 3600000 * 3 },
        resave : true,
        saveUninitialized : false,
        secret : 'njksndf323SDFsffdi32Sfsd34fsbkoqaz231j0'
    })
)
```

When I open in browser a route where session is used, the cookie (`connect.sid`) is correctly set.

The problem is that whenever I refresh a page, a number of new session files is being created in the sessions directory, but I think that after the cookie is set the same session file should be used for every request.

Why new session files are being created every request? What am I missing?

UPDATE:

the new session files are being created because all those calls are ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX client needs to support [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials) (which should be set to `true` to make the AJAX request pass cookies and/or authorizations headers).

For instance in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url       : URL,
  xhrFields : {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});
```

Note that this will require CORS support